# how to run a Simulink model in a Matlab M file in this way?

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink

I have simulink model "Mod_Sim" in simulink
with an input port "inp" and an output port "out".
I want to send inputs to this model, simulate it and then take the
corresponding outputs at every sampling time "Ts".
I want to simulate this model in this way for "N" time steps (in  terms of Ts).

More specifically, I want the following implementation:

At a given time step "k", I will have input u(k) (from some other source).
Then, I want to apply this input to  Mod_Sim and get the corresponding output y(k) from the model. I want to repeat this for N time steps.

How can I do such an implementation?

I will be happy for helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have all the inputs defined as a function of time for the time span of interest in your MATLAB workspace before you start the simulation.

Assuming you have `t` and `u` defined in the MATLAB workspace, and that your input port `inp` is at the root level of the model, you need to configure your model to use `u` and `t` for `inp`, as described in [Import Data to Root-Level Input Ports](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/importing-data-to-root-level-input-ports.html).

Once you have done that, you can [run the simulation using the `sim` command](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-sim-command.html), making sure that `'SaveOutput'` is on in the simulation options.

You can repeat that exercise `N` times in a `for` loop for example. The real key thing is having all your inputs defined in the workspace prior to starting the simulation.

**Edit based on comments**

It sounds like you want co-simulation, although you don't say what is generating the `u(t)`, whether it's another piece of software or whatever. Regardless, you have a couple of options as I see it:

1. Write an S-function to interact with the other piece of software generating `u(t)` so that it pulls a new value of `u` at each time step. This is actually quite hard to do, a lot of software vendors propose some form of co-simulation with Simulink via an S-function (e.g. [SimulationX](http://www.itisim.com/co-simulation/)). See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742427/co-simulation-with-simulink-stepwise-execution-and-interchange-of-parameters-wi) on the same topic.
2. Use TCP/IP or UDP/IP to communicate between Simulink and the third-party software. The Instrument Control Toolbox provides [Send and Receive blocks for TCP/IP and UDP/IP](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/direct-interface-communication-in-simulink.html). TCP/IP is supposed to be more reliable than UDP/IP, see [this comparison](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/tcpip-and-udp-overview.html).

Comment: I know this implementation and that is not what I want. My implementation will be online: t and u will be created with time and hence u cannot  be defined as a function of time  at the beginning.

Comment: Your question wasn't clear (or maybe it's just me). Anyhow, it sounds like you want co-simulation. This is actually really hard to do properly, you would need to write an S-function that would interact with the other software or whatever is generating `u(t)` and I wouldn't know where to start with this. The other option, if possible, would be send the data via TCP/IP or UDP/IP. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: What I want to do exactly is as follows (yes,  it is co-simulation).  There is a software "X" for which  it is possible to couple to Matlab but not possible to Simulink. There is a model "M" in X software. I designed a SISO controller "K" in Simulink for M. In the coupling  file "C.m" (which couples X to Matlab), I want to call K at every sampling time k to get u(k),  then  send  this u(k)  to M via C.m, and after M is simulated, I will get output  y(k) from  M in X  via C.m and  finally  I will  send y(k) to K. I will be happy  to learn how this will be executed. Thank you.

Comment: Then you need to write an S-function to perform the co-simulation, there is no way around it, although the vendor of your software X should provide this. It's very advanced stuff (and beyond my knowledge), and you need a thorough understanding of how both the simulink engine and the other software's engine work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742427/co-simulation-with-simulink-stepwise-execution-and-interchange-of-parameters-wi for a similar question. Good luck.